# iOS 7 Universal Back Button Image

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

This has been covered disparately in other questions and answers but this is a more general request for advice.

I am writing a scientific App so the titles in the Navigation Bar have a habit of being long. So I need to contrict the size of the back image or text.

If I do this at the View Controller level it works perfectly but it means inserting the code in every VC. E.g.

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 36.0f)];    
    UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12.0f, 0, 12.0f)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

As I want this to be consistent what is the best approach in iOS 7 to put it in the App Delegate so it is only instigated once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in my opinion would not be to put this in the App Delegate, It would be to create a subclass of `uiviewcontroller` and add it there in the `viewwillappear` than have all the view controllers in your app of "that" kind.